Have a sticky navbar on top of containing blocks
I have now been scratching my head a long time as to how to make a sticky navbar on top of the content of the page.
I have a webpage that contains a header, a main block, and a footer.
I want the main block to have a navbar to navigate easily among the different sections of its content. This navbar needs to be always accessible to the user while they are navigating inside the main block, which is why I want to make it sticky.
What makes it difficult though, is that I want the navbar to be on top of the content of the main block, to allow each section of the main block to have a background-color that extends to the full width of the page.
In the following example, I recreated something approaching what I want, except that each main content block needs to extend to the full width of the page.
How would I go about this?


.header,
.footer {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 40vh;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.nav > .navcontent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content > .block {
  height: 80vh;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}

.content > .block.-b1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.content > .block.-b2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.content > .block.-b3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
<header class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block -b1">
      <h1>My content</h1>
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam  velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa.  Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc  nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac  sollicitudin sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue  molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet,  turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae  ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula.  Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b2">
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam  velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa.  Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc  nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac  sollicitudin sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue  molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet,  turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae  ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula.  Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b3">
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam  velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa.  Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc  nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac  sollicitudin sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue  molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet,  turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae  ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula.  Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navcontent">
      <li>Link 1
      <li>Link 2
      <li>Link 3
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>




Should your navigation have a fixed width or be responsive?

I was going for a fixed width (that would depend on the user’s screen).

To solve that, I would probably use display: grid, and define overlapping areas for .content and .nav using grid-template-columns.
That is likely the most flexible solution regarding the HTML structure and styling.
And I would use a variable for the width of the navigation so that you could also use it for the padding on the right of your content.
That variable then could be changed with a media query depending on the screen size.


:root {
  --nav-width : 150px;
}


.header,
.footer {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 40vh;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content-start] 1fr [nav-start] var(--nav-width) [content-end nav-end];
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.nav>.navcontent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content>.block {
  min-height: 80vh;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: calc( 20% + var(--nav-width));
}

.content>.block.-b1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.content>.block.-b2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.content>.block.-b3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
<header class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navcontent">
      <li>Link 1
      <li>Link 2
      <li>Link 3
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block -b1">
      <h1>My content</h1>
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa. Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac sollicitudin
        sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet, turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae
        ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula. Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b2">
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa. Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac sollicitudin
        sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet, turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae
        ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula. Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b3">
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa. Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac sollicitudin
        sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet, turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae
        ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula. Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>




Using the grid positioning system was definitely the best option. What I ended up doing was to define .content and each .block as a subgrid, allowing them to use their parent (main) column tracks, and use that to position the text correctly. This meant I only had to define the navbar width once and that I didn’t need any variable. If unclear, I can provide the code.

@Mat, yes, subgrids are definitely an option to get a better setup for responsiveness. And nowadays, subgrid can be used - depending on the target audience. Btw whenever you find a better solution than the posted ones - even if it builds on one of the shown solutions - feel free to create your own answer and accept it as the solution. So create an answer that illustrates how to use subgrid to solve your problem.

By target audience, do you mean if targetting older / uncommon browsers?

Thanks for the tip. The way I did it better suits my particular needs and preferences, but both methods are equally valid to this particular question that I intentionnally intended to be as narrow as possible.

@Mat sure but you still should show it as an answer. Your question should not only  help you but anyone else with a similar problem. And with your solution present, anyone reading it has an additional option. And your solution will be the best one for various situations.

Okay, I just posted it.

One way to do this, would be to make .content go over the full width (flex: 0 0 100%;), and move the navigation that gets "pushed aside" by that, to the left again by its own width, using transform: translateX(-100%);
That approach left whitespace on the right, so slightly modified:
.navcontent get a fixed width (which you said you wanted to go with anyway), via flex: 0 0 3em;
And the full-width .content gets an additional margin-right: -3em; to counter the navigation's width.


.header,
.footer {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 40vh;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.nav > .navcontent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  flex: 0 0 3em;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-right: -3em;
}

.content > .block {
  height: 80vh;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}

.content > .block.-b1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.content > .block.-b2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.content > .block.-b3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
<header class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block -b1">
      <h1>My content</h1>
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam  velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa.  Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc  nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac  sollicitudin sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue  molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet,  turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae  ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula.  Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b2">
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam  velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa.  Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc  nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac  sollicitudin sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue  molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet,  turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae  ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula.  Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b3">
      <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam  velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa.  Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc  nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac  sollicitudin sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue  molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet,  turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae  ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula.  Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navcontent">
      <li>Link 1
      <li>Link 2
      <li>Link 3
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>




The problem with this approach is the empty space generated on the right of the page. Adding overflow: hidden to the main element solves it, except it breaks the sticky positioning…

You said you wanted to give the navigation a fixed width anyway, so above is a modified version, that doesn't translate the element, but gives the content a negative margin-right corresponding to the navigation's width.

This does work. It is not as practical as the grid system, as it and may force you to adjust, for each resolution, the .blocks’ paddings so that they do not go under the navbar and make centering the navbar and the block’s content hard or impossible. It is a bit harder to maintain too. It is a valid answer to the question nonetheless and probably the best alternative to using the grid positionning system.

Here is an alternative way to do it, using the CSS grid layout and subgrids, without using any variable or having to specify dimensions or positioning multiple times.
.main is the block containing:

the navigation bar (.nav),
and the .content.

By giving .main a grid layout, we can easily position the .nav element (parent of .navbar) whereever we want, and then make .content stretch over the entire width of .main.
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 5% 15% 1fr;
}

.nav {
  /** Puts the navigation bar on the first row, fourth column, over the .content */
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  /** Puts the .content on the same row as the navigation bar, and
  across all columns of the grid to make it take all the width. */
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}

1fr 50% 5% 15% 1fr are purely arbitrary values. This is where we define how we want our content, our text and our navbar to be positionned, as well as the space they occupy. Here, I plan to put my text in column of size 50%, but it could be any other size, in percentage or any other unit. 5% is the gap I want between my text and my navigation bar, 15% is the width I want for my navigation bar and the 1fr on both sides will center the text and the navigation bar.
We now have each .block full width as desired, but we want their text content to be positionned only on the second column (the one spanning 50% here). This makes sure the text is not hidden by the navigation bar. (It also centers the text properly, and ensures the gap of 5% between the text and the navigation bar.)
So each .block needs to use a grid layout as well. We can reuse the grid layout of the .main block by using subgrid on .content and then on each .block, without forgetting to make .block full width too.
.content,
.content > .block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
 }

/** Make each .block span all the width of the grid. */
.content > .block {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}

Finally, by adding an additional HTML element for each .block containing all their content, which we can name .blockcontent, we can position our text accordingly.
.content > .block > .blockcontent {
  grid-column: 2;
}



/**
  Setting up a basic example layout for the page.
*/
* {
margin: 0;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 40vh;
}

.content > .block {
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.content > .block.-b1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.content>.block.-b2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.content>.block.-b3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

/**
 * Code required for a sticky navbar
 */

.main {
  display: grid;
  
  /** Dimensions and positions need only be specified here and can be any value and unit.*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 5% 15% 1fr;
}

/**Navbar*/

.nav {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav > .navcontent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/** Content */

.content {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}

.content,
.content > .block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
 }



.content > .block {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.content > .block > .blockcontent {
  grid-column: 2;
}
<header class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navcontent">
      <li>Link 1
      <li>Link 2
      <li>Link 3
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block -b1">
      <div class="blockcontent">
        <h1>My content</h1>
        <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa. Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac sollicitudin
          sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet, turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae
          ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula. Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b2">
      <div class="blockcontent">
        <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa. Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac sollicitudin
          sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet, turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae
          ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula. Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block -b3">
      <div class="blockcontent">
        <p>Integer interdum varius diam. Nam aliquam velit a pede. Vivamus dictum nulla et wisi. Vestibulum a massa. Donec vulputate nibh vitae risus dictum varius. Nunc suscipit, nunc nec facilisis convallis, lacus ligula bibendum nulla, ac sollicitudin
          sapien nisl fermentum velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam commodo dui ut augue molestie scelerisque. Sed aliquet rhoncus tortor. Fusce laoreet, turpis a facilisis tristique, leo mauris accumsan tellus, vitae
          ornare lacus pede sit amet purus. Sed dignissim velit vitae ligula. Sed sit amet diam sit amet arcu luctus ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>




Indeed a nice solution.
